# google Analytics real time data, country master table

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to group the countries into groups using "Standard country or area codes for statistical use (M49)". while grouping, I need to compare the country name, for an example -from Google analytics Realtime api V3, I got the Country as “United States”  and based on the M49 the same country is mentioned as “United States of America”.

So Is there a way that I can get the Master table of country of google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Google [published their geographical id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/geoid#top_of_page)s as a csv file in their documentation for the measurement protocol. So download that file, open it in a spreadsheet software and filter the "target type" column for "country".